# How to determine if popup div is outside of browser

Tags: jquery, css, browser, css-position

I have a lot of popups, which i need to place everywhere on the page.

What i need is to determine if my opened popup goes outside of the browser's screen. If so, inverse the positioning. For example, by defaults, the popup use absolute positioning with `top:31px` and `left:5px` . So if the popup box goes outside of the screen, it should inverse the "left" into the "right" so it will stay in browser.

**Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aspirinemaga/ejyRR/12/**

I'am sure it should already be answered here, but i can't find it. Maybe someone can send me a link to already answered problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a JQuery expert so there will probably be a cleaner way to do this, but you could check if the `offset` of the element plus its `width` is larger than the width of the window:

```
var x2 = ($this).offset().left + ($this).width()
if( x2 > $(window).width() ){
    //change left to right
}
```

**Edit**

To fit it into the code sample that you have provided in your JSFiddle then you could do the following:

```
// Setting correct position for dialog
$(param).children('.gui-selectbox-dialog').each(function(index) {
    var x2 = $(this).offset().left + $(this).width();
    var side = (x2 > $(window).width() ) ? "right" : "left";
    $(this).css({
        'top':    heightBtn,
        side:    '0px'
    });
});
```

Please be aware that this will not work in the JSFiddle because it is using the window length of your browser, not the length of the `view` div in JSFiddle.

Comment: thanks for the code, but i can't get it work, will try a different method with your code. By the way here is a link **[http://www.tweaktown.com/reviews/4464/intel_dx79si_intel_x79_motherboard_review/index.html](http://www.tweaktown.com/reviews/4464/intel_dx79si_intel_x79_motherboard_review/index.html)** where you can check what i want to achieve. If you hover any of the image in article, the image will popup and will go with your mouse cursor. but when it will reach specific condition (edge of the screen) it will just inverse values of positions.

Comment: @aspirinemaga Sorry, I realised I was missing `.left` from the `offset()` object. Do you mean you cannot get it to work in the JSFiddle because that would be expected (since we are using window sizes). Check my ammended answer for sample code you can try in your project.

Comment: Thank you, i'am going to test it in a minute and will give you my feedback.